# How to handle "full" foreign-language date-strings in google-apps-script?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

Writing a JavaScript program in Google Apps Scripts, I'm encountering datetime strings  that look like 2nd line in

```
//German 
März 1, 2013 @ 19:00 - 23:00   
//"March 1, 2013 @ 19:00 - 23:00"
```

This needs to be parsed to two JS date objects (d1 = March 1, 2013  19:00; d2 = March 1, 2013 23:00)
 What is the best way to do this *in the Google Apps Scripts environment*?

For now I have written a custom function `lookupMonth()` to translate from German to English. I do this `string.replace(monthGer, monthEng)`.

```
function monthLookup(str) {
    //str1 = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" ")); //unicode blank!
    var pos = str.indexOf(/[0-9]/.exec(str)); //pos of first digit
    str1 = str.substring(0, pos  - 1 ).trim();

    var lookup = {
        "Januar": "January",
        "Februar": "February",
        "März": "March",
        "April": "April",
        "Mai": "May",
        "Juni": "June",
        "Juli": "July",
        "August": "August",
        "Spetember": "Septemper",
        "Oktober": "October",
        "November": "November",
        "Dezember": "December"
    };
    str = lookup[str1] + " " + str.substring(pos, 1000);
    return str;
}
```

This creates two new strings which can be to a `Date()` object, and then I could call `Utilities.formatDate()` Is there a better way?

Should I, for instance, call the translation service API (which would of course be much slower than calling an in-process JavaScript function?

Should I import a third-party library? If so, which one?